# Magento2 docker env, with wrong mysql port direction

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, magento2

i'm working on an local web dev environment of magento 2 projects in docker.

These are my important ports:

- NGINX_PORT=8000
- NGINX_SEC_PORT=3000
- PHPMYADMIN_PORT=8080
- MYSQL_PORT=8989

Everything works mysql, mysql access via phpmyadmin and access project via preinstalled apache path.

```
http://localhost/{path_to_project}/magento2/index.php
```

The problem now is there is a difference between the apache path and the nginx path I access via port e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

In both I added a pdo check in index.php:

```
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=mysql;dbname=Customer;charset=utf8;port=8989';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'user', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So if i go via apache http://localhost/{path_to_project}/magento2/index.php it shows that the connection to mysql works.

But when i go via nginx http://localhost:8000/ it shows that the connection refuses, in cause of port 3306 couldn't be access, but it should use port 8989 as I described.

I think there may be a problem with the nginx configuration, but there are no error logs or something else which i can use to solve this problem.

Files:

Nginx config:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  php:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
    include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - "./docker/etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./docker/etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
      - "${NGINX_APP_PATH}:/var/www/html"
      - "./docker/etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template"
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"
      - "${NGINX_SEC_PORT}:443"
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysqldb
  php:
    image: nanoninja/php-fpm:${PHP_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - "./docker/etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
      - "${NGINX_APP_PATH}:/var/www/html"
  myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "${PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"

  mailhog:
    container_name: mailhog
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - 1025:1025
      - 8025:8025
```

So if you have an idea or suggestion please contact me.

Thank you

Comment: If you change this line like so: `$dsn = 'mysql:host=mysql;dbname=Customer;charset=utf8;port=3306'` (so change the port), does this fix your problem?

Comment: Which part is failing?  Which part is supposed to be listening on port 8000?  `localhost` is extremely context-sensitive and just within this question can mean six different things (each container thinks it means "this container"); can you rephrase your question without using `localhost`, or make it clear where you're trying to resolve these URLs from?

Comment: @mihai No that won't work because my mysql database listen to port 8989 and theres no registered mysql service on port 3306.

Comment: @jschubert have you tried it? If your index.php runs in one of your containers that will solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I edited the question and tried to explain it as good as I can. I'm new in this kind of topics.

Comment: @Mihai Yes I tried it, it doesn't work because the mysql container only hears internally to port 3306 and for other containers or services it will be accessed via port 8989. And this service works, because I'm able to access it via apache or via software like phpmyadmin/sequelPro.

Comment: Communications between containers always use the internal port (3306) and ignore any `ports:` or `expose:` declarations.  I'm surprised you say the DSN in the question works.

Comment: I saw the problem: use my solution and also change the host name from mysql to mysqdb (the name of your service in your docker-compose.yml). So both the port and the host are wrong